# DeclarationError : undeclared identifier

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am writing the smart contract for lottery project. and this is the function in which one line causing error!

```
function WinnerOfLottery() public view returns(address){
        require(msg.sender==manager);
        require(participants.length >=3);
        **uint r=random();**
        address payable winner;
        uint randIndex = r % participants.length;
        winner= participants[randIndex];
        return winner;
    }
```

Comment: Which one is the line? thats a code block, Since its an undeclare identifier we would also need more of the code to see whats wrong

Comment: Can you share the `random()` function definition?

Comment: The random() is not defined , i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the decleration of the function and i made the function for generating random winners